# Where should I place the Facebook Like Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, facebook, web

It is said that javascript code must be place righ before the `</body>` tag. But after generating the Facebook Like button I get this message:

> Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the
>   opening `<body>` tag.

This is the code I have to add:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=675640525783719";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Comment: What is your question? As they said you need to place it just after the opening body tag.

Comment: can you post the full url please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as they say, put it rigth after the opening `<body>` tag:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=675640525783719";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

//rest of your code

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't particularly matter where you put it, so long it's **BEFORE** the `</body>` tag. Adding it to the top of the page (just after `<body>` makes sure that the SDK gets downloaded and is available to the page should any javascript further down the page try to access the `FB` object directly.

Your `<div id="fb-root"></div>` needs to be *above* wherever the `<script>...</script>` tag is placed, so the SDK can locate that div to add resources to it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late but I was doing some searching myself about this topic.

What that little bit of script is doing is actually downloading another script asynchronously (the one actually used for their API) and injecting it into the page.

By default, web browsers (at least old browsers) will stop rendering and wait while they download external scripts. This is why it's often recommended to put scripts at the end of the body. However, by loading the script asynchronously they don't block rendering.

Modern browsers support `async` script tags:

```
<script src="http://example.com/script.js" async>
```

Browser support for `async`: http://caniuse.com/#search=async

I think this is the better way to load a script asynchronously these days but Facebook wants the best support possible (IE9 and lower). If the browser doesn't support `async` then that attribute is ignored and the script should load just fine, although synchronously.

The one part I'm not sure of, which is why I was searching for answers myself is: why not put it in the `<head>` if you're already loading the script asynchronously? Why the beginning of the body specifically? That I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

In my research, it should be right after the body tag since it tries to load an iFrame then the script asynchronously. This is for performance and so that it doesn't block anything else you render.

Reference:
https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/under-the-hood-the-javascript-sdk-truly-asynchronous-loading/10151176218703920/

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late but I was doing some searching myself about this topic.

What that little bit of script is doing is actually downloading another script asynchronously (the one actually used for their API) and injecting it into the page.

By default, web browsers (at least old browsers) will stop rendering and wait while they download external scripts. This is why it's often recommended to put scripts at the end of the body. However, by loading the script asynchronously they don't block rendering.

Modern browsers support async script tags: