# facebook like button at the end, is it ok? even is facebook recommends putting it after the <body>

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I want to delay as much as possible the display of the facebook like button on my webpage, for many reasons, mostly because I want my page to download as fast as possible.

On the facebook page it says:
Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the **opening body** tag.

So, I added the following code right after the body tag

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Then, I decided to put that exact code at the very end and it looks like everything is working the same.

My question is why Facebook recommends putting the javascript SDK ideally after the opening body tag if there seems to be no consequence putting it at the end?

Is it ok to put the code at the very end? Is there something that I’m not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it anywhere as long as it is before `</body>` tag. I have used it myself at the end of the page without any problem, but there might be some side effect in some cases as the Facebook official documentation says

> This code works best when placed directly after the opening  tag.

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17571104/1656977)

> It doesn't particularly matter where you put it, so long it's BEFORE the `</body>` tag. Adding it to the top of the page (just after `<body>` makes sure that the SDK gets downloaded and is available to the page should any javascript further down the page try to access the FB object directly.
>
> Your `<div id="fb-root"></div>` needs to be above wherever the `<script>...</script>` tag is placed, so the SDK can locate that div to add resources to it.